# How to navigate without HyperlinkButton beatween two pages?

Tags: silverlight

I created two pages on my scratch silverlight application. 
The two pages are appear on the mainPage ( mainPage is a UserControl ).
Now, i want to see the page1 on the top and navigate to page2.

I can't add HyperlinkButton.

How can i add the page 2 ? 
And how can i navigate to page2 from page 1 ( can be from the mainPage that contain the page1 & page2 )

I try evrything and nothing work.

The code

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="FrameNavigator" Source="/Views/page1.xaml" >

   // need somehow to add here page2 

</navigation:Frame>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to show both pages at once?  And why do you not want to us a Hyperlink button.  If you want the user to be able to click on something and go to page2, but you don't want it to look like a HyperlinkButton, you can replace the Content of the HyperlinkButton.

```
<HyperlinkButton.Content>
    <Image ... /> <!-- or whatever --/>
</HyperlinkButton.Content>
```

If for whatever reason you don't want to use HyperlinkButton, you can navigate from code.

```
FrameNavigator.Navigate(uri);
```

Please be more specific as to what you are trying to do and I can give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I solve this problem in this way

Frame2.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 0):

Use Button Control for this

On click event you can navigate page in frameby

NavigationFrame.Navigate(uri)

try this

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MissionsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I am new to xaml and am just now starting to realize the design capabilitys so I do everything else in the code behind just make sure you have

```
using System.Windows.Navigation
```